# jQuery color animation plugin not working on FF

Tags: jquery, plugins, colors

I am using the following jQuery Color plugin:

```
/*
 Color animation jQuery-plugin
 http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/
 Copyright 2011 Edwin Martin <edwin@bitstorm.org>
 Released under the MIT and GPL licenses.
*/
(function(d){function i(){var b=d("script:first"),a=b.css("color"),c=false;if(/^rgba/.test(a))c=true;else try{c=a!=b.css("color","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)").css("color");b.css("color",a)}catch(e){}return c}function g(b,a,c){var e="rgb"+(d.support.rgba?"a":"")+"("+parseInt(b[0]+c*(a[0]-b[0]),10)+","+parseInt(b[1]+c*(a[1]-b[1]),10)+","+parseInt(b[2]+c*(a[2]-b[2]),10);if(d.support.rgba)e+=","+(b&&a?parseFloat(b[3]+c*(a[3]-b[3])):1);e+=")";return e}function f(b){var a,c;if(a=/#([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/.exec(b))c=
[parseInt(a[1],16),parseInt(a[2],16),parseInt(a[3],16),1];else if(a=/#([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])([0-9a-fA-F])/.exec(b))c=[parseInt(a[1],16)*17,parseInt(a[2],16)*17,parseInt(a[3],16)*17,1];else if(a=/rgb\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*\)/.exec(b))c=[parseInt(a[1]),parseInt(a[2]),parseInt(a[3]),1];else if(a=/rgba\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9\.]*)\s*\)/.exec(b))c=[parseInt(a[1],10),parseInt(a[2],10),parseInt(a[3],10),parseFloat(a[4])];return c}
d.extend(true,d,{support:{rgba:i()}});var h=["color","backgroundColor","borderBottomColor","borderLeftColor","borderRightColor","borderTopColor","outlineColor"];d.each(h,function(b,a){d.fx.step[a]=function(c){if(!c.init){c.a=f(d(c.elem).css(a));c.end=f(c.end);c.init=true}c.elem.style[a]=g(c.a,c.end,c.pos)}});d.fx.step.borderColor=function(b){if(!b.init)b.end=f(b.end);var a=h.slice(2,6);d.each(a,function(c,e){b.init||(b[e]={a:f(d(b.elem).css(e))});b.elem.style[e]=g(b[e].a,b.end,b.pos)});b.init=true}})(jQuery);
```

and when i try to animate a div using this code:

```
$(".container").prepend(data.latest).find(".item_row:first").hide().slideDown().animate({backgroundColor: '#fff9a5'}).animate({backgroundColor: '#ffffff'});
```

it throws this error in Firebug:

```
b is undefined
```

i even tried to use the unpacked version or even compile it using google closure compile app with no luck.

Comment: Providing more information (like your HTML) would be helpful. Also, recreating the problem on a site like JSFiddle would go a long way.

Comment: the thing is that it works on jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/24g9h/5/) but it doesnt work on my app... will check to see whats causing this not to work..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The element, which should be animated with this jQuery color plugin, must have a background-color before the animation started, e.g. set with css:

```
.item_row { 
    background-color: #000000; 
}
```

Also see this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/AzWr6/).